# find all p prime number such that : sum of divisor $p^{4}$ a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Problem :

determine all prime numbers such that :

$1+p+p^{2}+p^{3}+p^{4}=m^{2}$ , $m\in \mathbb N$
My try :

$p=2$ so we find : $1+2+4+8+16=31≠m^{2}$

$p=3$ so we find :

$1+3+9+27+81=9^{2}$

$p=5$ so we find :

$1+5+25+125+625≠m^{2}$ 
$.$
$.$
$.$
so how many numbers ??

if we find : 
$m^{2}≤1+p+p^{2}+p^{3}+p^{4}≤(m+1)^{2}$

then we can say no prime number $p>3$

but how I find $m,m+1$ ??

Comment: $1+3+9+27+81=9^2$? You mean it's $11^2=121$

Comment: This is a well-known question, see [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-p-if-p-is-prime-and-1-p-p-2-p-3-p-4-is-a-perfect-square-of-a-natural-number). Only $p=3$.

Comment: For large $k$ you have $k^4 + k^3 + k^2 + k + 1 \approx (k^2 + k/2)^2$. Fiddle a bit with that to see what value(s) $m$ might have.